# Do I need to call ReleaseIntArrayElements on an array created with NewIntArray?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a native method that does some work on a bitmap. Inside the method I grab the image data via a method call that writes the data to a `jintArray` parameter that I've created with `NewIntArray`:

`jintArray pixels = env->NewIntArray(width * height);`

I don't need to return this array back to the calling Java code - it's only for processing while in this method. Do I need to call `ReleaseIntArrayElements` on `pixels`? If so, what do I pass for the `elems` parameter, since I don't need to copy it back to a Java array?

`void (JNICALL *ReleaseIntArrayElements)
       (JNIEnv *env, jintArray array, jint *elems, jint mode);`

Comment: Have you called `GetIntArrayElements`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with it. It is a local reference and it will be cleaned up when your JNI method exits. As Edward Thompson hints above, `ReleaseIntArrayElements()` is the converse of `GetIntArrayElements().` It has no other function.

Comment: @anDroider Err, in the JNI Specification?

Comment: If the array changes after GetIntArrayElements() but before ReleaseIntArrayElements(), do I need to call setIntArrayRegion() before releasing the Array... or that is not required... Get and Release are sufficient ?

Comment: @Amit The only way the `jintArray` *can* change is via `SetIntArrayRegion().`

Answer (score 1):

You have to release only reference:

```
jintArray pixels = env->NewIntArray(width * height);
...
env->DeleteLocalRef(pixels)
```

Comment: You don't even need to do that in most cases: only when you are creating lots of local references in the JNI method. They all get released automatically when it exits.

Comment: Thanks, but I usually prefer to call it to make clear that resource is released even in small functions.

Comment: While user207421 is correct that you don't need to env->DeleteLocalRef() in MOST cases there are certainly cases where this is needed. One example of this is when using the JNI in the less common direction of calling the JNI from C/C++ to use code in Java rather then using it to call C/C++ methods from java. I found out the hard way and experienced massive memory leaks in my C++ program until i read @gerbit 's answer and used env->DeleteLocalRef() and all the memory leaks went away.